# Centering inline-block images

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div of inline-block images.
This is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class = "row">
        <div class = "icon"> <img src = "icon.PNG" alt="Some of the interesting stuff I've worked on."> </div>
        <div class = "icon"> <img src = "icon.PNG" alt="My past experiences."> </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.row{
   display: block;
}
.icon{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

the result is supposed to be the icons side-by-side and centered horizontally. Right now they are centered horizontally but they are all underneath eachother.

Help is greatly appreciated, I'm new to web development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thatt's because a div is a block element.  You will have to change the HTML element for icons to be an inline element such as a `span`

```
<span class="icon"> <img src="icon.PNG" alt="Some of the interesting stuff I've worked on."> </span>
<span class="icon"> <img src="icon.PNG" alt="My past experiences."> </span>
```

Or alternatively override the display property to `inline-block` on your icon class as shown below.

```
.icon {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/z7qfnem4/

Comment: Thanks, this lines them side-by-side but it doesn't center them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.row {
 text-align: center;
}

.icon {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

This works because `display: inline-block;` will allow `text-align: center;` to work on block level elements.